# AsyncTask not stopping while loading images.

Tags: android

This is my AsyncTask, called from getView of an adapter:

```
class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,String>{

        private ImageView imv;
        private String path;

         public LoadImage(ImageView imv) {
             this.imv = imv;

        }

         Bitmap userAvatarStream = null ;
            Bitmap IconStream = null;
            URL IconURL;

            ProgressDialog dialog;
            @Override
                protected void onPreExecute(){
                    //Setting all the variables by getting the ids from the layout


                return;

                }


                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

                    try {
                        IconURL = new URL(cr.ImageUrl);
                        IconStream = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(IconURL.openConnection().getInputStream());


                    }

                    catch (MalformedURLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }


                 protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                        // ImageView user_avatar = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.follower_user_avatar);

                    imv.setImageBitmap(IconStream);


                         return;


                }
```

The problem that I get here is that the images keep loading. Lets say I scroll down and the images go away to be refreshed again if I scroll up the list. It keeps making calls to get the images. This behaviour is obviously undesirable except at one place that if the internet on your cell-phone goes down and comes up again, this would help to auto-load the images. But, in the current state even that is crashing as it keeps making calls. How to stop AsyncTask from doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cache you images to filesystem or memory.

Each time you scroll the list `getView` is called. If you put the image loading method on `getView` and didn't use Image Caching then it'll download the images again and again. There are some opensource image loader for list with caching support.

One of them is `droidFu`. It supports two level of caching. Filesystem and memory. Get droidFu from following link.

https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu

Comment: What if there are lots of images? Will eat up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try a boolean flag to keep the check whether the image was loaded successfully or not.

If it was not then only make a call to Load Image Asynctask.

You may need to use a boolean array to keep the track if there are more than one row in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class performBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();  
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        callxmlparser();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (ringtoneNamelist != null && ringtoneNamelist.size() > 0) {
            songslist.setAdapter(new Songslist());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SongsList.this,"Network signal speed is too slow\ncannot parse the data from the server\n Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();   
    }
}
```